# console.log of parsed JSON returns undefined , but looks fine before parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

this used t work fine untile couple days of ago

lets say this is my php script :

```
  echo json_encode (array('stat'=>'ok'));
```

i send a ajax request to this script :

```
$.post(base_url+'line/finalize/' , {type:selected_type } , function(data){
   bet_inprog = false ;
   console.log('-------------------*'+data);
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
   console.log('-------------------*'+data);
   console.log('-------------------*'+data.stat);
 }
```

in firebug i see it returns

```
{"stat":"ok"}
```

in the console i get

```
-------------------*{"stat":"ok"}

-------------------*[object Object]

-------------------*undefined
```

what is going on ?

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(data)` after parsing?  Get rid of the string you are adding to it and just log the object.

Comment: For me, it works correctly. Are you sure it is undefined ? :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat i've already have ... it returns `[object Object]`

Comment: Are you not setting the content type on the server?

Comment: @epascarello i haven't done anything to server and it's config

Comment: @max: Are you using IE?  I wanted you to just do `console.log(data)` (*without* the `'-------------------*'+`).  In sane browsers (Chrome and Firefox... not IE), you'd see the object's contents.  Try `console.dir(data);`.

Comment: There is nothing you should do with the config...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-content-type-http-header-for-json

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to parse the JSON on your own, let jQuery do it.  It will do it anyway if you set the correct headers (`Content-type: application/json`).

If you pass a 4th parameter to `$.post`, you can tell jQuery to automatically deal with the parsing.

```
$.post(base_url+'line/finalize/', {type:selected_type}, function(data){
    console.dir(data);
    console.log(data.stat);
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $.parseJSON(data).  You don't need it.  You would need it if your data looked like this:

```
'{"stat":"ok"}'
```

I'm guessing that the server is wrapping the object differently and returning a different object.  That's why it's not working not but it used to.

Comment: I think he *does* need `$.parseJSON(data)`.  His first `console.log` printed `{"stat":"ok"}` and the second `[object Object]`.  That means he *did* parse the string into an object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - I don't know then.  When I create a fiddle and run his code, if I use a new version of jQuery, it blows up on the json parse.  If I use an older version (1.6.4), the parsed data returns a null and then blows up when trying to access the prop of a null object.  I'm using Chrome btw.

Comment: That's because jsFiddle sends the JSON with the correct Content-Type header.  This causes jQuery to automagically parse it for you.  This is not the case in the OP's example.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the info.  I came here to answer and walked out learning something myself.

Answer (score 0):

i donnu what was going on ! but i solve it by parsing my data in another variable

```
var parsed = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(parsed.stat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the dataType in above post requests, which tell ajax to accpet the result in specified dataType. The fourth parameter in $.post request is used to specify the dataType. i.e.

```
$.post(base_url+'line/finalize/' , {type:selected_type } , function(data), 'JSON'){
console.log('-------------------*'+data.stat);
 }
```

This would do your job..

Comment: That's not where the `,'json'` goes.  That's not even valid JavaScript syntax!